# Will my Dead of Winter game be abandoned if I buy Dead of Winter: The long night?

Tags: components, dead-of-winter

I have Dead of Winter and I was wondering what would happen if I buy it's expansion The long night, because it's a standalone. I know you can mix some cards, but I wish to know if my current board and general cards will be unused or duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things that are (mostly) duplicated in TLN: Colony and location boards (Colony board has different art, location boards are thicker), player boards, set of dice and tokens (TLN has two-sided tokens for barricades and helpless survivors because there are now different versions of those). Regular zombie standies have different art.

TLN also has all starting items and location decks, but their compositions are different - location decks have new items and some basic items have alternative uses there.

Other content: optional modules, characters, crises, crossroards, missions, objectives etc. are unique.

One point worth noting: there are rumors about new expansion [Warring Colonies](https://twitter.com/WatchItPlayed/status/761333615359844352) that allegedly uses content from both stand-alone boxes to create a new team vs team game mode.